# React hooks: am I doing an anti pattern? updating state in function outside the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am beginning to use React (hooks only), and facing a strange issue. I am trying to reproduce the problem in a small test code, but can't get it to happen, except in my full blown app. This leads me to wonder if I'm doing something really wrong.

I have an array of objects, declared as a state. I map this array to display its content. Except that nothing gets displayed (the array is filled, but nothing gets displayed). Now if I declare an un-related state, make it a boolean which flips each time my array gets updated, then my array gets displayed properly. As if, in the render phase itself, React did not detect the array's changes.

A few things:

- the array gets updated by a socketIO connection, I simulate it here with a timer
- I update my array OUTSIDE of my component function, BUT providing the setter function to the update function
- I also create part of the render fields outside my component function (this has no effect, just for readability in my full app)

I essence, this is what I am doing:

```
const updateArray = (setTestArray, setTestTag, addArray) => {
    setTestArray(prevTestArray => {
        let newTestArray = prevTestArray.map((data, index) => (data + addArray[index]))
        return newTestArray
    })
    setTestTag(prevTag => {
        return (!prevTag)
    })
}

const renderArray = (currentTestArray) => {
    return currentTestArray.map((data, index) => (
        <div>
            testArray[{index}]={data}
        </div>
    ))
}

function TestPage(props) {
    const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([])
    const [testTag, setTestTag] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        let samples = 3
        let initArray= []
        for (let i=0; i<samples;i++) initArray[i] = Math.random()
        setTestArray(initArray)
        // In real code: setup socket here...
        setInterval(() => {
            let addArray= []
            for (let i=0; i<samples;i++) addArray[i] = Math.random()
            updateArray(setTestArray, setTestTag, addArray)
        }, 1000)        
        return (() => {
            // In real code, disconnect socket here...
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <Paper>
            Array content:
            {renderArray(testArray)}
            <br/>
            Tag: {(testTag)? 'true' : 'false'}
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

This works just fine. But, in my full app, if I comment out everything concerning "testTag", then my array content never displays. testArray's content is as expected, updates just fine, but placing a debugger inside the map section show that array as empty.

Thus my questions:

- is my updateArray function a bad idea? From what I read, my prevTestArray input will always reflect the latest state value, and setTestArray is never supposed to change... This is the only way I see to handle the async calls my socket connection generate, without placing "testArray" in my useEffect dependencies (thus avoiding continuously connecting/disconnecting the socket?)
- rendering outside the component, in renderArray, doesn't affect my tests (same result if I move the code inside my component), but is there a problem with this?

As a side note, my array's content is actually more complex is the real app (array of objects), I have tried placing this in this test code, it works just fine too...

Thank you!

---

**Edit:** Note that moving updateArray inside the useEffect seems to be the recommended pattern. I did that in my full app. The hook linter does not complain about any missing dependency, yet this still doesn't work in my full app.

But the question is still whether what I am doing here is wrong or not: I know it goes against the guidelines as it prevents the linter from doing its job, but it looks to me like this will still work, the previous state being accessible by default in the setter functions.

---

**Edit #2:** Shame on me... silly mistake in my real app code, the equivalent of updateArray had a shallow array copy at some place instead of a deep copy.
Why adding the flipping tag made it work is beyond me (knowing the data was then indeed properly displayed and updated), but getting rid of this mistake solved it all.

I will leave this question on, as the question still stand: is placing the state update, and part of the rendering outside the component a functional problem, or just something which might mater on hide dependencies (preventing the react hooks linter from doing its job) and thus simply bad practice?

The fact is that things work just fine now with both functions outside the component function, which makes sense based on what I understand from hooks at this point.

Comment: I've tested the code you provided and it seems to be working fine

Comment: You can't setState outside of the declared function, this is the reason you are not seeing anything there.

Comment: @dev_junwen : right, this test code works just fine; but when doing the same thing in my full app, I don't get any display results

Comment: If the test code work, then its probably something wrong in your code

Comment: @yuri: thanks for answering. However this test code works. I understand the guidelines given concerning where to modify the state, but I cannot find a reference stating that what is being done here will not work? Trying to understand how React hooks really work, so I can debug this...

Comment: @Will59 If you make this update function were it should be, inside the function, do you still face this problems when running the full app? I understand than it does not, true?

Comment: @yuri: if I declare updateArray inside useEffect, it still does not work in my full app The array updates successfully (using a debugger inside updateArray, previous/new values move as expected), but it does not translate into anything in the render phase (wether I use an external render function, or inline the map section in the final return). In the render phase, the array is seen as empty!
As if React could not see the array got updated...

Comment: This may help you to avoid the not triggering problem https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824308413559668744?lang=en

Comment: Thank you both for taking time to answer!